# Office doesn‘t show updates but they are enabled

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

I have a problem with the office updates, hopefully you can help me. We have a GPO that says automatic updates are active and the channel to use is the monthly enterprise channel. For most of the computers this works quite well.

However, about 5% of the computers have the problem that they are stuck on a very old Office version (from 1904 to 2008 everything is there), and partly as channel Monthly is selected. I also have no way to manually trigger the update on the computers.

The only thing that helps is to completely uninstall Office and reinstall it. But to do this on more than 200 computers is a bit time-consuming, so I hope you still have a solution ready!

Comment: The only thing that helps is to completely uninstall Office and reinstall it.     .... Can you try (remotely logging into the computer) doing an Office Repair to see if that kicks off updates?  For whatever reason the machines did not update, the version now may be too old to automatically update.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! The quick fix didn't help, through the online repair it has now switched from ProPlus to Apps for Enterprise and updated to the latest version. However it is still on the Current channel and updates are still managed by the system administrator.